# Creating a Javascript Function That Iterates through JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How do you access the value of a key:value pair in JSON? Right now, the function iterates through the json and provide keys but not the corresponding values. So for instance, if I wanted the site value for each task of each employee, how would I do that?

```
var s = {
    "schedule": {
        "employees": {
            "1000": {
                "task1": [
                    {
                        "task": "task1",
                        "site": "site1",
                        "from": "0900",
                        "to": "1000"
                    },
                    {
                        "task": "task2",
                        "site": "site2",
                        "from": "0900",
                        "to": "1000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "2000": {
                "task2": [
                    {
                        "task": "task3",
                        "site": "site3",
                        "from": "0900",
                        "to": "1000"
                    },
                    {
                        "task": "task4",
                        "site": "site4",
                        "from": "0900",
                        "to": "1000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

for (var i in s["schedule"]["employees"]) {
    // this gives me the object, I would like the employee number (eg:1000)
    console.log([i]);
    for (var j in s["schedule"]["employees"][i]["tasks"]) {
        //how do I print the value for the "site" key?
        console.log([j]);       
    }
}
```

Comment: @tokyovariable: He did, needs scrolling though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(i); // employee number

console.log(s.schedule.employees[i].tasks[j].site); // task site
```

Comment: Hi, employees[i] is not valid as employees is not an array. employees is an object and "1000", "2000" are properties of that object.

Comment: @RocoCTZ, no its not an array but you can access its properties by using array syntax. And since you cannot do `employees.1000` etc you have to do it with the array syntax

Comment: @RocoCTZ: `({"1000": "still works"})["1000"] == "still works"`

Comment: @PatrickEvans So I can see that they're not arrays. But why is is that you cannot do employees.1000 etc and why do you use array syntax if it's not an array?

Comment: It's not really "array syntax". It is still object property access. `a.b` is always identical to `a["b"]`; but you can't always do the reverse - because some would be ungrammatical (like, e.g. your `employees.1000` example), or because the property name is not a constant (i.e. `employee.i` is wrong because we want the property of `employee` whose name is not `i`, but *in* `i`). Arrays in JS are just somewhat magic kinds of objects which are optimised to access integral keys, and have a magic property `length` which is autoadjusted whenever you assign to an integral key.

Comment: i.e. it's not objects that are using array syntax, but arrays that abuse object syntax, at least in JavaScript context. :)